# How can I execute a lisp function while pressing prefix key C-h and then let Emacs continue the normal processing of C-h?

Tags: emacs, key, elisp, prefix

I want to execute a lisp function while pressing prefix key C-h and then let Emacs continue the normal processing of C-h.
How can I do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating

```
(key-binding [(control h)])
```

I found out the command bound is `help-command`.  You can use an "around" defadvice to run your code.  See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: thank you. I have solved it. The cua-mode of Emacs has code doing this.

Comment: Hi.  I'm glad you were able to resolve your problem.  Can you elaborate on your solution as an answer so other people who come here through Google can get some useful information?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defvar smart-ime--state 'normal)
(defvar smart-ime--debug nil)
(defvar smart-ime--ena-prefix-override-keymap nil)
(defvar smart-ime--prefix-override-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(defvar smart-ime--keymaps-initialized nil)
(defvar smart-ime--keymap-alist
  `(
    (smart-ime--ena-prefix-override-keymap . ,smart-ime--prefix-override-keymap)
    )
  )

(defun smart-ime--init-keymaps ()
  (define-key smart-ime--prefix-override-keymap [(control x)] 'smart-ime--prefix-override-handler)
  (define-key smart-ime--prefix-override-keymap [(control c)] 'smart-ime--prefix-override-handler)
  (define-key smart-ime--prefix-override-keymap [(control h)] 'smart-ime--prefix-override-handler)
)

(defun smart-ime--prefix-override-handler (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (smart-ime--prefix-override-replay arg))

;; the most important part    
(defun smart-ime--prefix-override-replay (arg)
  (let* ((keys (this-command-keys))
         (i (length keys))
         (key (aref keys (1- i))))

    (ime-save-and-set-status 0)
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'smart-ime--post-command-handler)
    (setq smart-ime--state 'prefix)
    (setq smart-ime--ena-prefix-override-keymap nil)

    ;; Don't record this command
    (setq this-command last-command)
    ;; Restore the prefix arg
    (setq prefix-arg arg)
    (reset-this-command-lengths)
    ;; Push the key back on the event queue
    (setq unread-command-events (cons key unread-command-events))))


(defun smart-ime--post-command-handler-1 ()
  (cond ((eq smart-ime--state 'prefix)
         (setq smart-ime--state 'sequence))


        ((eq smart-ime--state 'sequence)
         (ime-restore-status)
         (setq smart-ime--ena-prefix-override-keymap t)
         (setq smart-ime--state 'normal)

         (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'smart-ime--post-command-handler)))

        (t
         (error "error state")))


(defun smart-ime--post-command-handler ()
  (when smart-ime-mode
    (condition-case nil
        (smart-ime--post-command-handler-1)
      (error nil))))


(define-minor-mode smart-ime-mode
  "Toggle Smart IME mode."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " SmartIME"
  :global t

  (unless smart-ime--keymaps-initialized
    (smart-ime--init-keymaps)
    (setq smart-ime--keymaps-initialized t))

  (unless smart-ime-mode
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'smart-ime--post-command-handler))


  (if (not smart-ime-mode)
      (setq emulation-mode-map-alists (delq 'smart-ime--keymap-alist emulation-mode-map-alists))
    (add-to-ordered-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists 'smart-ime--keymap-alist 400)
    (setq smart-ime--ena-prefix-override-keymap t))

  )

;;; Announce

(provide 'smart-ime)
```